# How much senior debt could be issued?

Tags: fixed-income

Is there a limit on how much senior debt could be issued? If a company issues a small amount of debt relative to its assets and wants to issue more could it still be called "senior" or it would have to be labeled junior because there is a small amount of outstanding debt that has priority when paying? Could the company issue a lot of debt relative to its assets and call it senior?

If somebody could provide a link to read about this, I would be grateful. I could not find anything

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about quantitative finance

Comment: This would be covered by a part of the covenants package under the trust indenture. If an issuer were to do this excessively, it would likely be an event of default.

Answer (score 1):

Covenants from the first issuance may restrict additional issuance or debt ratios.

https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/knowledge/finance/debt-covenants/